# _www password on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

Does anyone know what Apache (2.2) uses as it's password for the user the server runs under?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't have a password; you are expected to use `sudo` to become root, then `sudo -u _www` or `su _www`.